# Why is Javascript not handling these reserved words like a string key in this array?

Tags: javascript

I have the following test case in a coding kata for javascript:

***word-count_test.js**

```
var words = require('./word-count');

describe("words()", function() {

  it("handles properties that exist on Object’s prototype", function() {
    var expectedCounts = { reserved: 1, words : 1, like :1,  prototype: 1, and : 1, toString: 1,  "ok?": 1};
    expect(words("reserved words like prototype and toString ok?")).toEqual(expectedCounts);
  });
});
```

The following code will not pass this:

**code v1**

```
var words = function(phrase) {
    var wordCountAry = {};
    // split on whitespace, including newline
    phrase.split(/\s/).forEach(function(oneWord) {
        if (!wordCountAry[oneWord]) {
            wordCountAry[oneWord] = 1;
        } else {
            wordCountAry[oneWord]++;
        }
    });
    return wordCountAry;
};

module.exports = words;
```

But something like the following counter line will not trigger the error:

**code v2**

```
wordCountary[word] = (+wordCountary[word] || 0) + 1
```

So what is so special about that unary "+" operator?

Comment: `+"5" === 5` It's shorter than `parseInt`

Comment: you're not being clear here. What exactly are you trying to do? I don't see anywhere where you're restricting reserved words.. also +(Object) would be `NaN` so, it will always be `0 + 1`

Comment: What error exactly is being triggered?

Comment: Change `if (!wordCountAry[oneWord])` to `if (!wordCountAry.hasOwnProperty(oneWord))`

Comment: @royhowie: and `wordCountary[word]` is shorter than `+wordCountary[word]`.

Comment: @Nona have you tried to output what your function returns?

Comment: var wordCountAry = Object.create(null) and it'll work

Answer (score 1):

A standard JavaScript [object prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) has predefined properties, such as:

- `toString()`
- `constructor()`

When you test those property names using typical conditional logic, they will appear as existent, e.g.

```
var x = {};
if (x['toString']) {
  // this gets executed
}
```

The second code sample works around that issue with two tricks:

```
+x['toString'] || 0;
```

First, the property is coerced into a numeric value by using the unary plus operator. For functions or undefined values, the coercion yields `NaN`.

Secondly, the logical or operator is used to coalesce the left hand and right hand expression; if the right hand operand evaluates to `false` (that includes `NaN`) it will yield the right hand operand, otherwise it returns the left hand operand.

In this manner, either an undefined property value or a function value will yield `0` and therefore it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really about "reserved" names (those are another matter in JavaScript, e.g. `class` although it's not reserved anymore in ES6), but about inherited properties.

`wordCountAry` is an object, so it already has a `toString` method. So when you test

```
if (!wordCountAry[oneWord])
```

with the words "toString" the condition will be false (because `wordCountAry["toString"]` is trueish (it's a function).

So you need to use a condition that will work when the property is not a number (which is the case with the Number coercion of a function with unary `+`), or, to be safer, also check if it is inherited (`hasOwnProperty`).

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating your wordCountAry object, you can can pass null as the prototype, and this should solve your problem. So, instead of initializing it to {}, see how you can set it's prototype to null.